# How to get parallax effect on divs only

Tags: javascript, css

I am stuck while creating parallax effect on div boxes.

> requirement is when we scroll the div will be stick to the screen
>   while the subsequent div will create overlay effect on first div or
>   another words it slide over the first div.similarly other divs will
>   also have this sort of effect for reference https://www.jhu.edu/ code
>   is also provide here https://jsfiddle.net/cxos2vu7/1/

```
  <div id="parallex-1" class="parallax section stickbottom" style="height:768px">
    <div class="sticky">
        <video controls="controls" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" style="background-color:aliceblue">
            <source type="video/webm" src="https://www.jhu.edu/assets/uploads/2017/03/Homepage-Loop-28.webmhd.webm" />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section-2" class="parallax section stickbottom" style="height: 760px;background-color:black;">
    <div  class="sticky">
    </div>
</div>


<div id="section-3" class="parallax section stickbottom" style="height: 760px;background-color:black;">
    <div  class="sticky">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: less is more. it does not cost anything to use proper spacing and paragraphs when writing questions. to the question: i don't get it.

Comment: Try background-attachment:fixed. Demo: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm

Comment: question updated kindly review

Comment: there is no image in it.but i try  background-attachment:fixed.but its not woriking

Comment: please use http://scrollmagic.io/